# Select all dependencies

Tags: go, go-gorm

Imagine the following model:

```
type (

    Account struct {
        gorm.Model

        CustomID string `gorm:"index;unique"`
        Name string
        Profiles []*Profiles `gorm:"ForeignKey:AccountID"`
    }

    Profile struct {
        gorm.Model

        AccountID uint `gorm:"index"`
        TheFoo *Foo
        TheDoo *Doo
    }

    Foo struct {
        ProfileID uint `gorm:"index"`
        Boo string
    }

    Doo struct {
        ProfileID uint `gorm:"index"`
        Moo string
    }
)
```

All my attempts of getting the entire structure always fails. acc is always filled with only the account data and no profiles.

I even expereimented with this `db.Model(&acc).Related(&Profile{})` stuff but still no success. The (lets say, pretty bad) docs also do not clarify this.

```
var acc Account
db.Find(&acc, "custom_id = ?", myCustomID)
```

how would you actually do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the [Preload](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#preloading-eager-loading) method which supports ne, i.e.:

```
account := new(Account)
db.Preload("Profiles.TheDoo").Preload("Profiles.TheFoo").Find(account, "custom_id = ?", myCustomID)
```

I haven't checked yet if you actually need to preload `Profiles` as well, but it wouldn't hurt to use it if it turns out you do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your code for when you call the related function? http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html#has-many What Im seeing on the documentation for has-many it should look like this.

```
var acc Account
db.Find(&acc, "custom_id = ?", myCustomID)
db.Model(&acc).Related(&profiles)
```

Comment: That actually has the expected outcome but I would have expected that I can have it assembled already like in other ORMs.

otherwise I would have to iterate over Profiles to get the other relations right?